dotnet build get ErrorLog sarif version=2.1
I have dotnet core 5 and empty console app:
$ dotnet --version
5.0.408

just create hello world app .. and every possible way fails
$ rm *.sarif
dotnet build /p:ErrorLog="log21c21.sarif,version=2.1"
dotnet build /p:ErrorLog="log21s21.sarif;version=2.1"
dotnet build /p:ErrorLog="log21c2.sarif;version=2"
dotnet build /p:ErrorLog="log21s2.sarif,version=2"
dotnet build /p:ErrorLog="logdef.sarif"
head -2 log21c21.sarif
head -2 log21s21.sarif
head -2 log21c2.sarif
head -2 log21s2.sarif
head -2 logdef.sarif
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-1.0.0",
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-1.0.0",
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-1.0.0",
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-1.0.0",
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-1.0.0",

this is my env
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/sarif-1.0.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "runs": [
    {
      "tool": {
        "name": "Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler",
        "version": "3.11.0.0",
        "fileVersion": "3.11.0-4.22157.17 (55ad582d)",

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/55ad582d is later than https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/37148
tried --property:ErrorLog=log21.sarif,version=2, same thing in 6,7,8
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/src -w /src mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 bash

How do I get errors in sarif schema 2.1.0 ?

I think this is work for you i found on Github.
try it...

Percent-encoding doesn't work too

@jonny Did you found any solution from that github link. ??   which is i provided to you..
